# Github api with PHP

Tags: api, phpstorm, github-api

Im new in php and im trying to make a script who will create a new repository in github and catch a document that i have in my pc and make a commit in this new repository. This script will be executed in cmd. I search for github api and I have downloaded any folders with several files, i installed some things with a composer, but i cant create a new instance of github in my php.

I don't know anything about this, I spend two days in this and i cant write a function to talk with github. In the site of github developer I dont understand anything, I really need to do this, and im very lost. Im using PhpStorm 6.0.3.

What i cant understand:

1- The api is a folder with a lot of files? Or is a library who is imported in the phpstorm? How i put this in the phpstorm for i can get the methods and create my functions?

2- Where i get the methods for talk with the github api? Where i can see them? In github developer i dont understand nothing.

I see a question similar, but dont help me much.
Please help me

**EDIT**

I downloaded an api, and i use the composer require, apparently everything is fine, but when i execute some file to test the api, the same error pops up. The program cant find some files that is in the project, in the same folder. 
Ex: *PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Github\Api\ApiInterface' not found in D:\php-github-api-master\lib\Github\Api\AbstractApi.php on line 15*

In anothers files the same error appears, i put "use" referecing the files that im trying to use, but dont work. Ex: use Github\Api\ApiInterface;

**EDIT**

This code will create a new repository right? When i execute this code I get the error above, *Class 'Github\Api\AbstractApi' not found*, but the class is in there.

`class Repo extends AbstractApi
{
    public function create(
        $name,
        $description = '',
        $homepage = '',
        $public = true,
        $organization = null,
        $hasIssues = false,
        $hasWiki = false,
        $hasDownloads = false,
        $teamId = null,
        $autoInit = false
    ) {
        $path = null !== $organization ? 'orgs/'.$organization.'/repos' : 'user/repos';`

```
    $parameters = array(
        'name'          => $name,
        'description'   => $description,
        'homepage'      => $homepage,
        'private'       => !$public,
        'has_issues'    => $hasIssues,
        'has_wiki'      => $hasWiki,
        'has_downloads' => $hasDownloads,
        'auto_init'     => $autoInit
    );

    if ($organization && $teamId) {
        $parameters['team_id'] = $teamId;
    }

    return $this->post($path, $parameters);
}
```

}

Thanks,

Johann.

Comment: This is to broad of a question. Try narrowing it down to what problems you are facing. What is it that you don’t understand in the github docs?

Comment: Thanks, i have edit the question

Comment: About the first question, it looks like you don't know what an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is. In summary, an API can be viewed as a toolbox or a service, so it's more than *a folder with a lot of files*, APIs are functions than you call/use from your code.

Comment: See the API documentation about creating a repo: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

Comment: About this:  _APIs are functions than you call/use from your code_, but how i put this api in my phpstorm to call/use the functions? I tried somethings with a composer, and some commands in cmd, but i still cant call the functions.

Comment: I saw the documentation, but the code in there isn't php, how i transform that code in php? I can transform literal?

Comment: You don't have to transform anything, you need to **call** the API from your PHP code. You can try a PHP API client like this one: https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api

Comment: So you want to create a PHP script that you will call from PhpStorm? Your question is unclear, you mention a command then PhpStorm, how are these things related? Please **edit** your question. Have you tried to integrate GitHub in PhpStorm instead? https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-github-integration.html

Comment: I will write the script in phpStorm then i will execute the script with cmd. I edited the question, please check the edit

Comment: Please include your code in the question, we can't help you if there's no code to debug.

Comment: I edit the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finish my script, everything was done correct, sorry for my obviosly questions and thanks for who was answer me. My code:

```
<?php

include "vendor/autoload.php";

$client = new \Github\Client();
$username = "JohannLucas";
$password = "mypassword";

$method = Github\Client::AUTH_HTTP_PASSWORD;
//authenticate
$client->authenticate($username, $password, $method);

//Apagar Repositório
//$client->api('repo')->remove('JohannLucas', 'teste');

//Criar Repositório
$client->api('repo')->create('olamundo', 'Repositorio criado com o github api', 'http://my-repo-homepage.org', true);

//Commit

$committer = array('name' => 'JohannLucas', 'email' => 'johann.lucas@hotmail.com');
$path = "teste.txt";
$commitMessage = "Commit do teste.txt";

$content = "Olá Mundo!";
$branch = "master";
$repo = "olamundo";

$fileInfo = $client->api('repo')->contents()->create('JohannLucas', 'olamundo', $path, $content, $commitMessage, $branch, $committer);

print_r("Foi!");
```

Thanks!

Johann